# Git mirroring with bash scripting stuck in 3 for loop

Tags: bash, git, for-loop, repository

git1 ---> git3 (must use path1)

git2 ---> git4 (must use path2)

git1 can't clone to git4, or git2 can't clone to git3.Everytime it should work as above way.Script start to take git1 it has to be continue and hold next values with this way git1-git3-path1,when first loop finished it should be start second one like that git2-git4-path2

My scratch

```
A_sources=(git1 git2)
B_destinations=(git3 git4)
C_filename=(path1 path2)
workdir="/home/"




for A in "${A_sources[@]}"; do
    for B in "${B_destinations[@]}"; do
        for C in "${C_filename[@]}"; do
            git clone --mirror "${A}"
            cd "${workdir}/${C}"9
            git remote set-url --push origin "${B}"
        done
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one loop over indexes instead of three nested loops over elements, for example

```
# ensure the size are equal
(( ${#A_sources[@]} == ${#B_destinations[@]} && ${#B_destinations[@]} == ${#C_filename[@]})) || { echo "arrays sizes are not equals"; exit 1;}

for ((i=0;i<${#A_sources[@]};i+=1)); do
    git clone --mirror "${A_sources[i]}"
    cd "${workdir}/${C_filename[i]}"9
    git remote set-url --push origin "${B_destinations[i]}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you the answer, Im looking for :)